# How to find region bounding box of an object in image

Tags: python, opencv

I have the image and its mask like this:

[image: mask]

[image: original_im]

How can I use the mask to identify the rectangle bounding box around the object? So the final result should be this (with the background removed):
[image]

```
import urllib
from io import BytesIO

url_mask = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIyJ6.png"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url_mask)
mask = Image.open(BytesIO(f.read()))

url_im = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/msm7L.jpg"
f2 = urllib.request.urlopen(url_im)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(f2.read()))
```

Comment: Hi, please read the [mcve] to create a question that will be answered by the community.

Comment: cv2.boundingRect function with the list of white pixels in the mask

Comment: @Micka can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a fast way to do this (`cv2.boundingRect()`), but here's a way to think about how to do it from scratch.

Let's call your image `im` and the mask `im`, which I assume are NumPy arrays (or similar). Your goal is to find row indices `[row_low, row_high]` and column indices `[col_low, col_high]` such that the array `im[row_low:row_high, col_low:col_high]` is the sub-image that you're looking for.

If `mask` is an array of pixel values (probably 0's (black) and 255's (white)), start by converting it to a two-dimensional boolean array where an entry being `True` means you have a white pixel at that part of the mask (this isn't strictly necessary but it helps to see what's going on).

```py
>>> mask.shape
(758, 734, 3)                    # The original mask, with RGB layers.
>>> mask2d = mask.mean(axis=2)   # Get a single black-and-white mask.
>>> mask2d.shape
(758, 734)
>>> bmask = (mask2d == 255)      # Or maybe (mask >= 200) to be safe.
```

Now for each row and column, you can use `np.max()` to determine if that row or column has `True` in it or not (meaning there is a white pixel in that row or column of the mask). You can do this for all of the columns at once by specifying `axis` in `np.max()`: `axis=0` will check if there's a `True` in the column, and `axis=1` will check if there's a `True` in the row.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> bmask.shape           # Here's the boolean mask.
(758, 734)                # It has 758 rows and 734 columns.
>>> rows_with_white = np.max(bmask, axis=1)
>>> cols_with_white = np.max(bmask, axis=0)

# Check shapes.
>>> rows_with_white.shape
(758,)
>>> cols_with_white.shape
(734,)
```

The location of the first and last `True` in `rows_with_white` give you `row_low` and `row_high`, respectively, and similarly for `cols_with_white`. We can get them both with `np.argmax()`, which finds the *first* location of the largest value (which, for boolean arrays, is `True`). To get the location of the last `True`, we can simply reverse the array and repeat the process. These are negative indices, which indicate that we're counting backward from the end.

```py
>>> row_low = np.argmax(rows_with_white)
>>> row_high = -np.argmax(rows_with_white[::-1])
>>> col_low = np.argmax(cols_with_white)
>>> col_high = -np.argmax(cols_with_white[::-1])

>>> print((row_low, row_high), (col_low, col_high))
(85, -85) (174, -164)
```

Now that you have the indices, you can simply slice the original image to get the cropped one.

```py
>>> im_cropped = im[row_low:row_high, col_low:col_high]
```

And here's the whole thing put together, which assumes you already have `mask` and `im` defined.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> bmask = (mask.mean(axis=2) == 255)
>>> rows_with_white = np.max(bmask, axis=1)
>>> cols_with_white = np.max(bmask, axis=0)

>>> row_low = np.argmax(rows_with_white)
>>> row_high = -np.argmax(rows_with_white[::-1])
>>> col_low = np.argmax(cols_with_white)
>>> col_high = -np.argmax(cols_with_white[::-1])

>>> im_cropped = im[row_low:row_high, col_low:col_high]
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your code but the values of row_low and row_high are over my image. Also, ```rows_with_white``` and ```cols_with_white``` have shape (758,3) and (734.3)

Comment: Try flattening your mask into a two-dimensional array first, `mask = mask.mean(axis=2)`. This smashes the RGB layers together into a single black-and-white layer, which is what you want anyway.

Comment: In case ```row_high``` or ```col_high``` =0, you need to set them to ```-row_low``` or ```-col_low```

Comment: ^yes. Another way to handle this problem a little more robustly is to do `row_high = n_rows  - np.argmax(rows_with_white[::-1])` where `n_rows = len(rows_with_white)`. This sets it to the correct positive index instead of using negative indices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using cv2, then you could look trough all pixels and find  xmin, xmax, ymin ymax that equal 1. Since black is usually represented as 0 and white as 1.

Comment: Im using cv2 or some common image processing libraries